# pg_dump com plink.exe(putty)

Tags: postgresql, ssh, putty

Preciso executar alguns comandos ssh no meu servidor linux, de uma maquina windows via cmd.

Para isso estou utilizando o plink.exe

**Comando:**

```
plink -ssh root@192.168.3.87 -pw 12345 -m script
```

**Script:**

```
pg_dump -U master dados -v -Fc -f /sistema/dados/dados.bak
```

Esse comando funciona normal quando utilizo comandos nativos no script, como `cp`, `mv`, etc.

Para comandos como `pg_dump`, `pg_restore`, `createdb`, ele diz que o comando não foi encontrado.

PS.: O mesmo acontece usando o putty.exe pelo cmd do windows.

Answer (score 0):

A solução para esse problema, foi colocar o caminho inteiro do aplicativo. 
Ex.: `/opt/postgres/bin/pg_dump`.

Ainda não sei o porque, mas ele não reconhece nenhum desses comandos externos, quando executado pelo terminal do windows.